# Using a hostname on Apache rather than an IP

Tags: apache, dns, xampp

I am wanting to run a hostname on apache (on xampp) and I have changed the httpd.conf file so that `ServerName example.com`.

I then changed httpd-vhosts.conf so that

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/example"
    ServerName example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/example.com.log"
    CustomLog "logs/example.com.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and then added `127.0.0.1       example.com` to the hosts file in the System32->drivers->etc folder.

It works on the computer running xampp (I think because that has the altered hosts file) but it will not work from other computers on the same network, which I gather is supposed to be handled by the virtual hosts file.

Comment: "which I gather is supposed to be handled by the virtual hosts file." No. The Apache configuration tells Apache how to respond to each HTTP queries it gets, which website it knows about, etc. It has no consequences on how the traffic reach it. For that, you first need name resolution, which means the DNS or changes in each client hosts file (or equivalent) to make sure your website name is mapped to your Apache server IP adress. So something to do completely outside of any Apache configuration.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek is there a way I can do this for the whole network (so phones and other devices work too) or is this the only way

Comment: Install a local recursive client that will be authoritative for the names you need (ex: `dnsmasq`). and configure all clients to use it. Or register any domain in any TLD and just create records (using your registrar DNS servers for example) like `website1.priv.example.com` or `website1.int.example.com`, etc. mapped to the needed IPs.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks, I have some googling to do now though :)